# What is a good way to measure shift in nested regular polygons?

Tags: python, math, polygon

Well, let's say we have a task to draw nested regular polygons using turtle module in python. I came up somehow with an algorithm to do that using functions (func. that draws a polygon given its size and number of vertices, func. that converts the circumradius of a previous polygon into the apothem of the next one and etc.) and loops. The problems i have are:

- I haven't come up with a good measure for a shift that a turtle makes moving from the vertex of a previous polygon to the vertex of the next one. As you can see from the image below, there are not enough space between nested polygons. What I did was simply put the shift's size as a difference between circumradii (as shown in the code below)
- The points where a turtle finishes the shapes of each next polygon, starting from hexagon, start to shift downwards

What can you suggest i should do to improve my code?

Here is the code i wrote:

```
import turtle
import math

turtle.shape('turtle')

def prmn(num, size, draw):
    if draw == True:
        angle = 180-(360//num)
        turtle.left(180-angle//2)
        for i in range(1, num+1):
            turtle.forward(size)
            if i != num:
                turtle.left(180-angle)
            else:
                turtle.right(angle//2)
    if draw == False:
        inner_angle = 360//num
        inner_radius = (size*math.cos((math.pi/num)))/(2*math.sin(math.pi/num))
        outer_radius = size/(2*math.sin((math.pi/num)))
        chars = [inner_angle, inner_radius, outer_radius]
        return chars

def rad_conv(num, outer_radiu_prev):
     inner_angle = 360//num
     outer_radiu = outer_radiu_prev/math.cos(math.pi/num)
     return outer_radiu

def new_size(num, outer_radiu):
    new_size = 2*outer_radiu*math.sin(math.pi/num)
    return new_size

def rad_fw(outer_radiu_new, outer_radiu_prev):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(outer_radiu_new-outer_radiu_prev)
    turtle.pendown()


ns = 40
for i in range(3, 16):
    prmn(i, ns, True)
    rad_fw(rad_conv((i+1), prmn(i, ns, False)[2]), prmn(i, ns, False)[2])
    ns = new_size((i+1), rad_conv((i+1), prmn(i, ns, False)[2]))
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

And here what it should look like:

[image: the thing]

I've changed the code a little, the second part of it (funcs. *rad_fw*, *rad_conv*, *new_size*), here it is:

```
def rad_conv(num, outer_radiu_prev):
     inner_angle = 360//num
     outer_radiu = outer_radiu_prev + 20
     return outer_radiu

def new_size(num, outer_radiu):
    new_size = 2*outer_radiu*math.sin(math.pi/num)
    return new_size

def rad_fw():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.pendown()


ns = 60
for i in range(3, 12):
    prmn(i, ns, True)
    rad_fw()
    ns = new_size((i+1), rad_conv((i+1), prmn(i, ns, False)[2]))
```

But still it doesn't look that neat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that we can get closer to your ideal solution than your original solution using a lot less code:

```
import turtle

radius = 50

for sides in range(3, 16):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - 25)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.circle(radius, steps=sides)

    radius += 25

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Perhaps your ultimate solution is simpler than you're trying to make it.

[image]